# Text is not visible for first Row in GridLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

We are using GridLayout and the firstrow(in bold) is not visible in the below xml.
Only first TextView is not visible.All other texts are visible.
Would be very helpful if someone helped  us on this. Thanks in Advance
API level is 21

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
android:background="@drawable/gradientbg"
android:columnCount="2"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:rowCount="8"
android:useDefaultMargins="true"
tools:context="com.example.truesolution.Page2" >

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/display_message2"
     android:layout_column="0"
     android:layout_columnSpan="2"
     android:layout_row="0"
     android:text="@string/Sessions"
     android:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="278dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:text="@string/Value" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display_message3"    
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:text="@string/Licensing" />

   <Button
        android:layout_width="132dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:text="@string/Value" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/display_message4"    
       android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="4"
       android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:text="@string/DesktopFailures" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="131dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:text="@string/Value" />

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: You haven't set textcolor for the first textview wherein you have set for rest of the textviews. Whats your @drawable/gradientbg? The xml seems fine for me. I can see the text!

Comment: its a background image. tried adding color. no luck

Comment: okay.! I tried removing your BG,dimens and text colors it works for me.

Comment: which dimensions? we removed height from textview. did not work..

Comment: I mean to say, in order to test I removed the dimens in your layout as i dont know the dimen details.

Comment: so it must be an ecclipse issue

Comment: If it is an eclipse issue, you must be able to see when you deploy it on an emulator or device.?